# In Facebook developer dashboard, web payment option is missing in +add product section

Tags: facebook

I want to add web payment to my application and according to tutorial there is a option to add web payment in add product tab but I cannot see any option there.

[image]

Comment: That looks like a very old version of the app dashboard, even for apps created ages ago I don't get to see that any more. Try going to `https://developers.facebook.com/apps/{your-app-id-here}/payments/` directly, that's where the Setup button under "+ Add Product" should take you to anyways.

Comment: It redirects me to dashboard.. :(

Comment: The I’d suggest you file a bug report. https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/